# How to remove a specific value that is based on a specific date

Tags: r, date, duplicates

Below is a portion of my dataframe:

```
    Year Date        Location Tag Section domsec atDominantLocation
    2017 2017-08-13        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-14        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-15        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-16        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-17        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-18        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-19        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-20        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-21        a wnd       b      n                  0
    2017 2017-08-21        a wnd       u      n                  0
    2017 2017-08-23        a wnd       f      n                  0
    2018 2018-08-21        a wnd       f      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-18        a wnd       h      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-19        a wnd       o      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-15        a wnd       s      s                  1
    2018 2018-08-17        a wnd       s      s                  1
    2018 2018-08-14        c wnd      ss      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-16        a wnd       t      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-21        a wnd       t      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-13        c wnd      ww      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-20        a wnd       y      s                  0
```

The column "atDominantLocation" contains "1"s and "0"s. I want to keep all the "0"s but only keep the "1" with the earliest date. So, there should ONLY be one "1" for each tag and year and that "1" should be the earliest date in that year.

Below is my desired output:

```
    Year Date        Location Tag Section domsec atDominantLocation
    2017 2017-08-13        a wnd       n      n                  1
    2017 2017-08-21        a wnd       b      n                  0
    2017 2017-08-21        a wnd       u      n                  0
    2017 2017-08-23        a wnd       f      n                  0
    2018 2018-08-21        a wnd       f      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-18        a wnd       h      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-19        a wnd       o      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-15        a wnd       s      s                  1
    2018 2018-08-14        c wnd      ss      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-16        a wnd       t      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-21        a wnd       t      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-13        c wnd      ww      s                  0
    2018 2018-08-20        a wnd       y      s                  0
```

I've tried both the duplicate and unique functions without any success. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'Year', 'Tag' and create the logical expression in `filter` to subset the rows  - create separate logical expressions and join them with `|` (OR)  i..e. as we want all 0 values (`atDominantLocation == 0`) and only the row with `min`imum 'Date' where the 'atDominantLocation' is 1 (`Date == min(Date[atDominantLocation == 1])`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
   group_by(Year, Tag) %>%
   filter(atDominantLocation == 0| 
     ( Date == min(Date[atDominantLocation == 1]))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 × 7
    Year Date       Location Tag   Section domsec atDominantLocation
   <int> <date>     <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>               <int>
 1  2017 2017-08-13 a        wnd   n       n                       1
 2  2017 2017-08-21 a        wnd   b       n                       0
 3  2017 2017-08-21 a        wnd   u       n                       0
 4  2017 2017-08-23 a        wnd   f       n                       0
 5  2018 2018-08-21 a        wnd   f       s                       0
 6  2018 2018-08-18 a        wnd   h       s                       0
 7  2018 2018-08-19 a        wnd   o       s                       0
 8  2018 2018-08-15 a        wnd   s       s                       1
 9  2018 2018-08-14 c        wnd   ss      s                       0
10  2018 2018-08-16 a        wnd   t       s                       0
11  2018 2018-08-21 a        wnd   t       s                       0
12  2018 2018-08-13 c        wnd   ww      s                       0
13  2018 2018-08-20 a        wnd   y       s                       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Date = c("2017-08-13", 
"2017-08-14", "2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-17", "2017-08-18", 
"2017-08-19", "2017-08-20", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-23", 
"2018-08-21", "2018-08-18", "2018-08-19", "2018-08-15", "2018-08-17", 
"2018-08-14", "2018-08-16", "2018-08-21", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-20"
), Location = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "a"), 
    Tag = c("wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", 
    "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", 
    "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd"), Section = c("n", "n", 
    "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "b", "u", "f", "f", "h", "o", 
    "s", "s", "ss", "t", "t", "ww", "y"), domsec = c("n", "n", 
    "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "s", "s", "s", 
    "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s"), atDominantLocation = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: This works beautifully, @akrun! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` option is to `filter` `atDominantLocation` to just the `1`s. Then, sort and group by `Year` and `Tag`, then get the row with the earliest date using `slice`. Then, we can bind those rows back to the original dataframe, but just to the rows where `atDominantLocation` is `0`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(atDominantLocation == 1) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Tag) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(atDominantLocation == 0)) %>% 
  arrange(Date)
```

**Output**

```
    Year Date       Location Tag   Section domsec atDominantLocation
   <int> <chr>      <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>               <int>
 1  2017 2017-08-13 a        wnd   n       n                       1
 2  2017 2017-08-21 a        wnd   b       n                       0
 3  2017 2017-08-21 a        wnd   u       n                       0
 4  2017 2017-08-23 a        wnd   f       n                       0
 5  2018 2018-08-13 c        wnd   ww      s                       0
 6  2018 2018-08-14 c        wnd   ss      s                       0
 7  2018 2018-08-15 a        wnd   s       s                       1
 8  2018 2018-08-16 a        wnd   t       s                       0
 9  2018 2018-08-18 a        wnd   h       s                       0
10  2018 2018-08-19 a        wnd   o       s                       0
11  2018 2018-08-20 a        wnd   y       s                       0
12  2018 2018-08-21 a        wnd   f       s                       0
13  2018 2018-08-21 a        wnd   t       s                       0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                              2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                              2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), 
                     Date = c("2017-08-13", "2017-08-14", "2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-17", "2017-08-18", 
                              "2017-08-19", "2017-08-20", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-23", 
                              "2018-08-21", "2018-08-18", "2018-08-19", "2018-08-15", "2018-08-17", 
                               "2018-08-14", "2018-08-16", "2018-08-21", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-20"
                              ), Location = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
                                              "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "a"), 
                     Tag = c("wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", 
                             "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", 
                             "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd", "wnd"), 
                     Section = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "b", "u", "f", "f", "h", "o", 
                                 "s", "s", "ss", "t", "t", "ww", "y"), 
                     domsec = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "s", "s", "s", 
                                "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s"), 
                     atDominantLocation = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: This works great as well, @Andrew Gillreath-Brown! Thank you!

Comment: @Bluecanoe You're welcome! Consider upvoting if it works well.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df)

rbindlist(
  list(df[, .SD[atDominantLocation == 1][1], by = list(Year, Tag)],
       df[atDominantLocation == 0,]), use.names=TRUE) %>% 
  .[order(Tag, Date)]

#>     Year Tag       Date Location Section domsec atDominantLocation
#>  1: 2017 wnd 2017-08-13        a       n      n                  1
#>  2: 2017 wnd 2017-08-21        a       b      n                  0
#>  3: 2017 wnd 2017-08-21        a       u      n                  0
#>  4: 2017 wnd 2017-08-23        a       f      n                  0
#>  5: 2018 wnd 2018-08-13        c      ww      s                  0
#>  6: 2018 wnd 2018-08-14        c      ss      s                  0
#>  7: 2018 wnd 2018-08-15        a       s      s                  1
#>  8: 2018 wnd 2018-08-16        a       t      s                  0
#>  9: 2018 wnd 2018-08-18        a       h      s                  0
#> 10: 2018 wnd 2018-08-19        a       o      s                  0
#> 11: 2018 wnd 2018-08-20        a       y      s                  0
#> 12: 2018 wnd 2018-08-21        a       f      s                  0
#> 13: 2018 wnd 2018-08-21        a       t      s                  0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>